# Should you train/test split when using softimpute/matrix completion?

Tags: r, matrix, data-imputation, svd

I am trying to impute missing values on a large dataset. After reading the paper(s) introducing matrix completion via soft-SVD thresholding, as well as the softImpute R package vignetter by Hastie (https://hastie.su.domains/swData/softImpute/vignette.html), I haven't found anything that suggests the need to train/test split for fitting and completion of the matrix. But I wonder if that is necessary to get more valid results? E.g., should it be something like:

```
fit <- softImpute(x)
imp <- complete(x, fit)
```

Or should it be something like:

```
samp <- sample(1:nrow(data), 0.8 * nrow(data))

train <- data[samp, ]
test <- data[-samp, ]

fit <- softImpute(train)
imp <- complete(test)
```

I am struggling with this, so any thoughts would be welcomed! Thanks.

Comment: Welcome here! I guess that imputation is for you a means to an end, and you want to have a dataset without missing data to do something else. Could you tell us that is your final goal with the data? That might be relevant to answer your question.